# Update location of `axvspan`

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, error-handling, polygon

I want to 'simulate' the location of two objects in a plot. I wanted to do this with `axvspan`. I want to move one `axvspan` with a slider. I want to do something like I this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

t = 2
g0 = 10

filter_loc, = plt.axvspan((50-g0-t), (50-g0), color = "blue")
sensor_loc = plt.axvspan(50,80, color="red")
plt.axis([0, 1, -10, 10])

axgap = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
sgap = Slider(axgap, 'Gap', 0.01, 30.0, valinit=g0)

def update(val):
    gap = sgap.val
    filter_loc.set_xdata(50-gap-t,50-gap)    
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

sgap.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

When try it in several ways I always get the error:

```
filter_loc, = plt.axvspan((50-g0-t), (50-g0))
TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable
```

So it seems to me that the axvspan does not like the updating of the values by using the slider. Are there ways I can still achieve this by using axvspan?

Answer (score 4):

You've an extra comma right after `filter_loc`.
Besides that, `filter_loc` doesn't have a `set_xdata` attribute. You may modify it by calling `set_xy()`, for example something like this will do:

```
def set_xvalues(polygon, x0, x1):
    _ndarray = polygon.get_xy()
    _ndarray[:, 0] = [x0, x0, x1, x1, x0]
    polygon.set_xy(_ndarray)

def update(val):
    gap = sgap.val
    set_xvalues(filter_loc, 50-gap-t, 50-gap)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

BTW the current `plt.axis()` values are preventing the blue square from being shown.